# Room: deleting a ForeignKey or setting the ForeignKey to a default value

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, android-room

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity(indices  = {@Index("address")},
    foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(
    entity = Address.class,
    parentColumns = "address",
    childColumns = "address",
    onUpdate = CASCADE,
    onDelete = SET_DEFAULT))
public class Human {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;

    @NonNull
    public String name;

    @NonNull
    public String address;
}

@Entity
public class Address {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    public String address;

    public int someInt;
}
```

I add "humans" with different addresses which I later try to delete or edit using:

```
@Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
void add(Human human);
```

Options that I see and problems with them:

1. I have a list of addresses of which one is "default". When I delete an address, I would like the "Humans" residing at the deleted address to "move" to "default".
   I used:

   ```
   @Query("delete from Address where address = :address")
   void deleteAddress(String address);
   ```

so onDelete = SET_DEFAULT does not seem to work as I imagined if I set a default value to address in the Human Entity.

This currently fails with: **NOT NULL constraint failed.**

2. An alternative to the deletion would be to edit an address and set it to "default" and thus merging with the existing "default" entry.
   I tried:

   ```
   @Query("update Address SET address = :address WHERE address = :addressToEdit")
   void editAddress(String addressToEdit, String newAddress);
   ```

This currently fails with: **UNIQUE constraint failed.** because there's already an address with the same name, obviously.

3. Setting the address to @Nullable in both Entities. In this way, the "default" address is null. This adds extra complexity to my solution(would not prefer it) and it seems that I'm not able to query the Humans with a null address using the following code because it does not return anything.

   ```
   @Query("select * from Human where address = :address")
   LiveData<List<Human>> getHumans(String address);
   ```

How can I achieve this setting to default of a deleted address(foreign key)?

Comment: Please act on [mcve]. Show what you have tried.

Comment: @philipxy: I edited my question. The rest would be regular boilerplate code to create a Room database.

Comment: If you won't give text that people can cut & paste & run on a clean system then why do you expect others to? Also you seem to not have understood important aspects of that. Eg: Your errors are at runtime. They depend on the start state. But you don't give it. Etc. [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/3404097)

Comment: @philipxy I don't expect anyone to run what I typed above even if it's trivial for someone who used Room before but I do expect that the solution is obvious for someone more experienced than me with Room and SQL. The details of the problem are plenty in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best solution so far which is working is to use the third option from the question with:

```
    @Query("select * from Human where address is NULL")
    LiveData<List<Human>> getAllHumansWithNullAddress();
```

As in using NULL as default.

`Address` remains the same but Human becomes:

```
@Entity(indices  = {@Index("address")},
    foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(
    entity = Address.class,
    parentColumns = "address",
    childColumns = "address",
    onUpdate = CASCADE,
    onDelete = SET_NULL))
public class Human {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;

    @NonNull
    public String name;

    @Nullable
    public String address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to modify your address entity and add id field as integer auto incremented. then in the Human Entity you can reference addresses by the id field. so before you delete the address record you can update the Human records which using the reference you want to delete by the default reference id for example : 1 then you can delete this address record by its id. here you can solve the address unique constrain issue.

Comment: This is not even close to ideal because it adds overhead in two places:
1. You could have multiple addresses with the same String name and different ids. When I list them, I want them to be unique. Using your proposal I would have to remove duplicates and merge together Humans having the same address name (but different ids).
2. The extra update of Human when I delete an address.

Comment: I know that it is not the optimal solution but it is a work around one. Plus you apply unique constraint to the address field to prevent double eneries for the same address string.

Answer (score 0):

currently room doesn't support onDelete = SET_DEFAULT action and room treats it as same as onDelete = SET_NULL so i suggest the following:-

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(
                entity = Address.class,
                parentColumns = "address",
                childColumns = "fk_address_id",
                onUpdate = CASCADE,
                onDelete = SET_DEFAULT))
public class Human {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;

    @NonNull
    public String name;


    @Nullable
    public String getFk_address_id() {
        return fk_address_id;
    }

    public void setFk_address_id(@Nullable String fk_address_id) {
        this.fk_address_id = fk_address_id;
    }

    //default address doesn't work on delete as room doesn't support
    // on delete set default and treat it like set null
    @Nullable
    public String fk_address_id = "default address";

    public Human(@NonNull String name,  @Nullable String fk_address_id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.fk_address_id = fk_address_id;
    }

}
```

and here is the address entity where the address field is unique.

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"address"},
        unique = true)})
public class Address {
    public void setAddress(@NonNull String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    int id;


    public String address = "default address";


    public int someInt;

    public Address(@NonNull String address, int someInt) {
        this.address = address;
        this.someInt = someInt;
    }

}
```

and in HumanDao you can get the null referenced address and update them to the default one.

HumanDao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Human where fk_address_id IS NULL")
Human[] getNullRef();
```

AddressDao:

```
@Update
void updateAddresses(Address... addresses);
```

AsyncTask class

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(getApplicationContext());
            Address address = db.addressDao().getAddress("address to delete");
            if(address != null) {
                db.addressDao().delete(address);
                Human [] humans = db.humanDao().getNullRef();
                for(int i =0; i < humans.length; i++) humans[i].setFk_address_id(DEFAULT_ADDRESS);
                db.humanDao().updateHumans(humans);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I'll use NULL as default as in the accepted answer because of no overhead.